# rounding Grid Fill edges

Tags: modeling, topology, retopology

Grid Fill often solves topology problems on the tops and bottoms of cylinders but it also adds subtle corners to an object.   Is there any way around this?

A shade smooth or more subdivisions is not going to get rid of this effect in a render.

Here are two examples:
[image: A bolt factory bolt with a custom top, and grid fill used twice]

[image: a wooden pedestal with a cylinder shape, grid fill is used top and bottom]

Comment: Perhaps try selecting all the faces on the "top" and inset them slightly? This may or may not be viable depending on your future topology needs, but it will fix the shading.

Comment: Thanks, I will use this advice in the future.  I think I see where I went wrong now.